# Best way to redirect to home if didn't have permission to access mvc2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I no have ideia how I will do this.

I am migrating application classic asp to mvc 2, because part of platform is in mvc2.

I have control of menus, pages , etc. But if user didn't have permission to access specific page and he put url this page will show but user not will do nothing in this page.

I want when user access a page without permission to redirect to home.

I try to do this in Globa.asax in events `Application_BeginRequest` and `Application_EndRequest`

In `Application_BeginRequest` and `Application_EndRequest` all request will appear in all calls .css, .imgs .etc.

in `Application_BeginRequest` and didn't show the url I want to really confirm that user has permission or not

`Application_EndRequest` is the first url showed to me is url I access but, i can't redirect to view if user didn't have access.

I'm lost, if somebody had a hint to give to me will be welcome.

Comment: Why don't create a filter?

Comment: if you're using [roles](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/2898/working-with-roles-in-aspnet-identity-for-mvc), you can use something like `IsInRole('Admin'){DoSomething...}`

Comment: Problem `Roles` is because I need to change all platform and manager don't want this.

Comment: I not know about `Filter` I will study this. thank you